# evolution 3.16 cannot open encrypted office 365 message

Tags: encryption, evolution, ms-exchange, office365

I have successfully configured Office 365 with Evoltion 3.16.x in Ubuntu 15.10.

While most emails can be read easily, the ones that are encrypted fail to open up with the following message

```
Could not parse S/MIME message: Cannot decrypt: you are not a recipient, or matching certificate and private key not found.
```

Usually in Outlook 2013, it automatically picks up the key of the user from the db, how can I get Evolution to retrieve the key ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution.

1. Export the user certificate from Windows / Outlook in .pfx format
2. Import the certificate in Evolution via **Edit -> Preferences -> Certificates -> Import**

The only drawback is that it will ask you for the certificate password every time you open Evolution.